# jQuery UI Sortable: Detects whether a table cell already has an item in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

First, here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/wLsCD/2/

What I am trying to achieve is to remove the ability of putting the two items in one cell.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
receive: function(event,ui){
   if( $(this).find('.item').size() == 2 ){
      $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
   }
}
```

Hope this helps